# Try to add a user to a multiple user field in the itemUpdating eventreceiver: The field you are trying to update may be read only

Tags: event-receivers, user, item-updating

I am using Sharepoint 2013. I have created a custom list. This custom list is using a custom contentype. In this custom contenttype I have a custom column. This column is a people picker. It is possible to select multiple users. In c# code I have created in vs an eventreceiver on itemupdating. I would like to add a new user to my people column. See code below how my code looks:

```
public override void ItemUpdating(SPItemEventProperties properties)
        {
            base.ItemUpdating(properties);

            var testManyUsers = properties.ListItem["TestManyUsers"];

            if (testManyUsers is SPFieldUserValueCollection)
            {
                SPFieldUserValueCollection sPFieldUserValueCollection = (SPFieldUserValueCollection)testManyUsers;

                SPUser currentUser = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser;

                sPFieldUserValueCollection.Add(new SPFieldUserValue(properties.Web, currentUser.ID, currentUser.Name));

                SPField spField = properties.ListItem.Fields["TestManyUsers"];
                properties.AfterProperties[spField.InternalName] = sPFieldUserValueCollection;

            }
        }
```

Ive got this error:

Invalid data has been used to update the list item. The field you are trying to update may be read only.

Answer (score 2):

You need to disable the readonly property, enable AllowUnsafeUpdates, update the item and update the list:

```
myWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

                    //Set the read only mode of people picker column to FALSE
                    currentitem.Fields["Betrokken specialisten"].ReadOnlyField = false;


SPFieldUserValueCollection sPFieldUserValueCollection = (SPFieldUserValueCollection)values;

                            SPUser currentUser = properties.Web.CurrentUser;

                            sPFieldUserValueCollection.Add(new SPFieldUserValue(properties.Web, currentUser.ID, currentUser.Name));

                            //Setting the property of people picker column
                            currentitem["Betrokken specialisten"] = sPFieldUserValueCollection;

                            //Update List Item
                            this.EventFiringEnabled = false;

                            currentitem.Update();
                            //Update List
                            currentList.Update();

                            //Set the read only mode to TRUE
                            currentitem.Fields["Betrokken specialisten"].ReadOnlyField = true;

                            //Update the List item again
                            currentitem.Update();

                            //update the List again
                            currentList.Update();

                            this.EventFiringEnabled = true;
```